# How to make CICD work for multiple repositories dependent with each other

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

if a system is deployed with code from multiple repositories, and these repositories are dependent. i.e. the system works only if a code is updated to one repository, and the corresponding code is updated to another repository at the same time. Then in this case, How should I make CICD work?

BTW, I have created an AWS Codepipeline for one repository, and I can do the same thing for another repository. But if these two repositories have to sync with each other, I am not sure what else I need to do with Codepipeline. Thanks.

Comment: This is a common problem for all traditional CI systems (based on post-commit verifications) because they rely on individual repository commits as action triggers and have no (easy) way to handle changes spanning multiple repos. By contrast gating CI systems (based on pre-commit verifications) use as triggers the submissions of candidate changesets and can thus natively support multi-repo changesets (but that's just one positive side-effect of their operation, among other, even more important advantages). Disclaimer - I'm the creator of one such system - ApartCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools which may help you achieve this kind of deployment, one of them is deploybot.

Since I use deploybot for my workflow I'd normally setup something like this:

First I would have to connect the main repository to Deploybot. Then Deploybot has the ability to treat other repositories as submodules and do the build process on a container inside deploybot, this means all the code from different submodules would be pulled to a container where you can execute different commands against your code and after the build finishes the same code will be deployed to your server.

Comment: Thanks John, since you are the only answer, I accept it. I will try.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you'll find DeployBot useful also :)